# My calendar won't work on my iPhone 4 since upgrading to iOS8. I am unable to save events

Tags: icloud, iphone, calendar, ios

All my history and future events (except birthdays attached to my contacts) are gone and I can't save new events.  When I view my calendar in iCloud from my computer they are all there.  They're just not syncing with my phone!  I don't have my calendar in my phone synced to any other calendar either. How can I resolve this?

Comment: Have you maybe accidently turned of syncing for iCloud? If not then try to disable and then enable it again.

Comment: Are you sure it's an iPhone 4 and not a 4S? The oldest device that iOS 8 supports is the iPhone 4S.

Comment: I'm having his problem with my iPhone 4s. The add button is not greyed out, I can add things to the calendar but it won't save. It shows up on the other calendars that I have synced, but not to my iphone, which it one of the more important places. Any ideas? I've rebooted my phone and checked the cloud settings. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with this for quite a while. Out of nowhere, I could not add any events or reminders to my calendar, and the (+) in the corner of my calendar was grey. Super frustrating!

Go under **settings.** Select **Mail, Contacts, Calendars.**  You must click on individual accounts, and move the slider for **calendar** to the "on" position. For instance, I have an iCloud account, and multiple gmail accounts listed. I clicked on each account, and turned on all of the calendar sliders.

This fixed the problem, and I am now able to add events, and view birthdays and events.

Answer (score 0):

To save new events to your Calendar go to **Settings > Mail, Contacts, Calendars**.

I clicked on Hotmail and then turned on **Calendars**. After that the gray `+` went red and I can now save events again.